# Javascript - onclick event is not working

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code:

```
window.onload = function () {make_buttons ('calc'); }

function make_buttons (id) {
    console.log (id);
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(input);
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode (i);
        btn.appendChild(t);
        document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn).onclick=document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").value=i;    
    }
};
```

Now when I have created the button with the for loop, it should also have the onclick event attached to it which writes the current value of i into my input form.

Code I have written produces no errors but when the button is clicked, it simply does not do anything. Why is that?

New version:

```
window.onload = function () {make_buttons ('calc'); }

function make_buttons (id) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = 'text';
    input.id = 'inp';
    document.getElementById(id).appendChild(input);
    for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
        var btn = document.createElement ("button");
        btn.id = i;
        var txt = document.createTextNode (i);
        btn.appendChild(txt);
        var make_btn = document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn);
        make_btn.onclick = button_pressed (i);
    }
};

function button_pressed (id) {
    document.getElementById("inp").value += id;
};
```

Comment: Would be great to leave feed back when voting a post down. Would be able to learn and make my next question better then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection that you should iterate through.
You need to go in loop through retrieved elements and assign the `value` attribute to each of them.

So that you can change

```
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn).onclick=document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT").value=i;
```

to something like this:

```
var id = 'my-form',
    btn = document.createElement('input');
btn.type = 'button';
btn.value = 'Click me!';
btn.onclick = function() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    // NodeList to Array if needed:
    // var inputsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs);
    for(var i = 0, l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
        inputs[i].value = i;
    }
    return false;
};
document.getElementById(id).appendChild(btn);
```

[**DEMO #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/EXLe4/)

---

### Update:

About your second question, yes it won't work in this way since at the time when your `onclick` event handler is called it's using the last value assigned to `i` variable. To avoid this you can just use [**closures**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

For example,

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" id="my-form">
    <input type="text" id="inp" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var btn,
    input,
    form,
    createHandler;
input = document.getElementById('inp');
form = document.getElementById('my-form');
createHandler = function(i) {
    return function() {
        input.value += i;
    };
};
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = 'Append ' + i;
    form.appendChild(btn);
    btn.onclick = createHandler(i);
}
```

[**DEMO #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/9QpEC/)

Also you can use just immediately invoked anonymous function to create that closure in the body of your loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // ...
    btn.onclick = (function(theNumberToAppend) {
        return function() {
            input.value += theNumberToAppend;
        };
    })(i);
}
```

[**DEMO #3**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/HmG2T/)

Comment: For some reason it is still not printing the values into the text field.

Comment: Also can you explain to me why it has to be like you showed?

Comment: @molecular  I tried to get it with Id but I dont know how to add a ID to the input field I have created with that code..

Comment: Just edited the question. The first version had only the information about the need in loop.

Comment: Allright, I will see to this code and try to apply it to my solution now.

Comment: I edited my original answer. This is how my code looks like now. But when I load the page, input field has number 9 in it and buttons don't add anything else into the text field.

Comment: Ah I changed the .value = to .value +=   and now it enters all the numbers from 1 to 9 into my text field.  But it should execute the button_pressed function only when I click the button.